# Xcode/Swift: Display "print" that I added to CocoaPod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using Swift 5, Xcode 10 & iOS 12.

I added the "FilesProvider" ([click](https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider)) as a CocoaPod to my project and it's working but now I want to test some stuff and for this I added a couple of `print`s to one of the library's .swift files.

How I did it:

- navigate to `Pods - Pods - FilesProvider` in the Project Navigator
- open the right .swift file in there
- add the `print`s
- unlock the file (Xcode asked if I wanted to do it) and save it
- run my app in the simulator

The added `print`s aren't being printed in the console though. I'm pretty sure that I added them to functions in the library that are being used by my app.

Do I have to use any special settings to display the `print`s of a CocoaPod?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually after editing the code inside your cocoapod, you'll need to clean before running again so the changes would take effect. But I would suggest using breakpoints.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I did `Product - Clean Build Folder`, afterwards it gave me a „no such module“ error for the import but after a `Product - Build` it's now displaying the prints. :) Is this the right "clean" or is there another one I should rather use?